# How to implement the following data transferring in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

First I have to create a column in the end of table

If there exist the data in the original column , move them into the new column

If the original column has no data now
 (because they must be nullable ,  so that there is chance the column has no data, the column will be deleted)

The problems are:
move from col to new col is `insert into new col {select old colmn from table}` ? 
Then how can I check the column exist no data / all col is null.

Also, How can I check datatype and whether it is null in pdo ?

Thank you

Comment: Why do you need to create a new column? Why can't you alter the existing column?

Comment: because some of the data is correspond to the old column
for the same column, one should be in col A, one should be in col B

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add a column to a table:

```
alter table myTable add column 'columnName' <column-specifications>
```

If you want to insert values from another column into this column:

```
update myTable set columnName=originalColumn
```

If you want to remove a column from a table:

```
alter table myTable drop column columnName
```

That being said, like Jeff Paquette mentioned, are you sure you want to create a new column?  I don't really understand the point of creating a column to insert values from another column.  Won't renaming your original column do the exact same thing?

```
alter table myTable change column ...
```

Comment: Thank you, also , how can i check a column only have null value?

Comment: And  How can I check datatype and whether it is null in pdo?  Thank you again

Comment: You can do `select * from myTable where column is not null` and see if you get any rows.  Use `count(*)` instead of `*` if you want the number of rows.  If you want to see the data type, do `describe myTable` .